# invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError), nothing helps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, rake

I start having an error all of a sudden whenever I run `rake db:create`. The error is

```
rake aborted!
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in `block in trace_on': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:328:in `trace'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:183:in `display_error_message'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:169:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `standard_exception_handling'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rake:23:in `load'
  from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I did

```
me@ubuntu:~ export LANG="C.UTF-8"
me@ubuntu:~ export LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"
```

I got

```
me@ubuntu:~ echo $LANG
en_US
me@ubuntu:~ echo $LC_ALL
en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Does `locale -a | grep C.UTF-8` produce anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try adding, as first line of the files touched by this task, the string:

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

These files may be all your custom initializers, your database.yml, etc

Comment: Thanks Alive.. that saved my Time Accepting answer cheers...!

Answer (score 7):

```
find . -name *.rb | xargs grep -P "[\x80-\xFF]" -l | xargs sed "1i # encoding: utf-8" -i
```

try this to fix every .rb file

UPD: tested on ubuntu only.

Comment: You sire made me find those rubbish files !

Comment: The grep flags used here doesn't seem to agree with Macs.

Comment: Put single quotes around *.rb for some OS/bash setups.  Thanks for this hack to workaround this bug - unfortunately did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If your name contains a non-US ASCII character (mine has a "Ö" in it), you get lost using Bitnami Redmine stack, since they record that name without any changes to the setup.rb file. It causes this exact error notification 'invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)'. As soon as I renamed myself in that file to "oe" everything worked fine! (after rake db:migrate)